# The best JavaScript libraries supporting Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, javascript

I have downloaded and installed Bitcoin full node on my Linux server and I'd like to start working with the bitcoin core to create wallet, addresses, and transactions. What is the best JS libraries available to facilitate using all the necessary methods in this regard?

Comment: The question can be [opinion based](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) I don't like JS and won't consider anything as BEST. However I found interesting resources on https://bitcoin-studio.com and they are using [BitcoinJS](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend bcoin:

https://bcoin.io/
https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin

It is a nodejs library that can also run a fully validating node, SPV node, and BIP44 wallet. It's used in production by many long-standing bitcoin companies such as Purse.io

You can even use the bcoin client to make RPC calls to bitcoin core, and of course you do not need to run the bcoin full node to take advantage of the library for TX construction and wallet functions.

Answer (score 0):

[You can search github for popular open-source projects with the query "bitcoin core javascript".](https://github.com/search?q=bitcoin+core+javascript)

The results will show you the most popular libraries on [github](https://github.com) at the moment!

I used [bitcoind-rpc](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcoind-rpc) by [bitpay](https://bitpay.com), and it worked well for me. There may be other libraries that work better for you. Just [search on github](https://github.com/search?q=bitcoin+core+javascript), [gitlab](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+core+javascript+site%3Agitlab.com), or other open-source repository hosts.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib
Bitcoinjs-lib lets you create and sign transactions

Comment: Couldn't get their library to create valid addresses on testnet.