# How do I build a webwallet soultion for BTC to allow subscribed users deposit their funds, allow to withdraw whenever required by the user?

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

I am new to bitcoin development. I am going through documentation and researching to build below in the webwallet solution

1. Create a HD Wallet which can assign addresses to subscribed users.
2. BackUp / Restore HD wallet on a different machine for managing any risks.
3. Allow user to withdraw funds as needed by processing a Withdrawal transaction if the user is sufficient funds in his account.

Comment: Could you provide a broader context? What is the target use case? There is hundreds of web wallets on the market, including some open source solutions.

Comment: Exploring to develop some functionality in an existing solution where Crypto can be used as mode of payment by consumers for exchange for services or exchange it for FIAT.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing existing open source solutions, it would be great if you could point me to any. Thanks

Comment: Lightning Network will be better for payments. [Btcpayserver](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver) is an open source payment processor that can be used for integrating bitcoin payments in websites. Resources related to LND: https://docs.lightning.engineering/community-resources/resource-list

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC API with any language that is used for web development. There are two ways to do this:

**Libraries**

There are few libraries that will help you develop web applications for Bitcoin. Example: [The best JavaScript libraries supporting Bitcoin Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99935/the-best-javascript-libraries-supporting-bitcoin-core/)

OR

1. Experiment with [Bitcoin Core RPC](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/) related to wallets on testnet. Once you understand how things work, run bitcoind with below bitcoin.conf:

   ```
   testnet=1
   server=1

   test.rpcport=PORT
   rpcuser=USERNAME
   rpcpassword=PASSWORD
   ```
2. Run [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) (There is also [Postwoman](https://github.com/hoppscotch/hoppscotch) but I have not tried it)
3. Create a request with URL: https://127.0.0.1:RPC_PORT/
4. Select 'basic auth' and enter RPC credentials
5. Body(raw):

   ```
   {"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "createwallet", "params": ["DW1",false,false,"",true,true]}
   ```
6. This will create a descriptor wallet with name 'DW' if you send the request. For using it in your web application, you can click on `</>` code symbol and copy the code for one of the languages:

[image: postman-bitcoin-core]

Few things related to security: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/JSON-RPC-interface.md

*There can be more ways or better ways to achieve the same. I am not a web developer. Just trying to help.*

Comment: Thank you for providing the details to point me in the right direction. Do you know if there is any documentation that I can refer to for setting up a HD Wallet for this purpose, and the processes for a wallet backup and wallet restore.

Comment: There is RPC command for almost everything. Create HD wallet: [`createwallet`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/createwallet/), Backup wallet: [`backupwallet`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/backupwallet/). Basic steps for recovery: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102904/recovering-and-transferring-bitcoin-to-new-wallet/